# Left join with 2 tables Return all records from the 1st table and a conditional field from the 2nd

Tags: join, distinct

I have 2 columns:
[tblCustomer]
`ID    |   DebtNr  |   CustomerName

1   |   10001   |   CustomerNr001

2   |   10002   |   CustomerNr002

3   |   10003   |   CustomerNr003

4   |   10004   |   CustomerNr0ab

5   |   10008   |   CustomerNr0yy

6   |   10012   |   CustomerSomeName`


[tblInquiry]


`ID  |   CustID  |   IsInquiryReady

1   |   1   |   True

2   |   1   |   False

3   |   6   |   True

4   |   2   |   False`


I want to return all Customers (so in this case 6 records). In addition, if at least 1 Inquiry is not ready (finished), an additional field with a value [False]

[result]

`ID  |   DebtNr  |   CustomerName    |   IsAtLeastOneNotReady

1   |   10001   |   CustomerNr001   |   True

2   |   10002   |   CustomerNr002   |   True

3   |   10003   |   CustomerNr003   |   False

4   |   10004   |   CustomerNr0ab   |   False

5   |   10008   |   CustomerNr0yy   |   False

6   |   10012   |   CustSomeName    |   False`


This Query returns 7 records:
`SELECT [tblCustomer].ID, [tblCustomer].CustomerName, [tblCustomer].DebtNr, [tblInquiry].ID, [tblInquiry].IsInquiryReady
FROM [tblCustomer] LEFT JOIN [tblInquiry] ON [tblInquiry].CustomerID = [tblCustomer].Id;`

Is this possible? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
select a.id, a.debtnr, a.customername,(select 'true' from dbo.tblinquiry b where b.custid = a.id and isinquiryready = 'false') as IsAtleastonenotready from dbo.tblcustomer a
```